# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: Error on Payu custom browser library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, payu

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':AppName:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/payu/custombrowser/BuildConfig.class

Unfortunately, the above error is the only thing that we have as information about this error. When we are trying to build the app for release it finds duplicate entries. These files are from the `Payu` library and if you delete them from the hard disk they are again auto generated while compiling and causing the `duplicate entry error`. Also, 23 `BuildConfig.class` files exist in the entire folder(including Facebook, `Google play store`, Payu, `Image loader` libraries). Now, I am not sure which file to delete which to keep. Deleting the files is useless as it is again auto generated.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is not that multiple JARs have `BuildConfig.class` entries but that you have at least two JARs that have this file in the same package path (`com/payu/custombrowser`). Or you are loading the JAR file twice.

Comment: Great man. You saved my day. Was stuck on it for 2 days wondering what the issue was. Thank you for helping me. Wish you the best for the future.